# Response.REdirect within an IFrame

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe, response.redirect

I have this situation of redirecting my asp page from a button within an IFrame.

Response.Redirect in the button click event redirects the IFrame but not the entire page.

Thanks,
Vishnu

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add a `target="_top"` to the html `<form>` element, or redirect using javascript `window.top.location = '/path'`.

If you have multiple iframe pages,  you may want to create a generic page, let's call it `FrameRedirector.aspx`. Place this code in the body:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.top.location = '<%=Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["url"])%>';
</script>
```

Then, replace the `Response.Redirect` code with

```
string redirect = "/path/to/redirect.aspx?foo=bar";
Response.Redirect("~/FrameRedirector.aspx?url=" + Server.UrlEncode(redirect));
```

Comment: Note that this solution is not secure enough as-is, without protecting against XSS/Redirection validation